# BitTorrent Peer Handshake

Tags: ruby, networking, tcp, p2p, bittorrent

I'm trying to send a BitTorrent handshake to a peer but it's not working. Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong? `len` is supposed to come back with something, but it's currently nil.

```
require 'bencode'
require 'digest/sha1'

file = File.open('./python.torrent').read
info_hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(a['info'].bencode)

# Here's what parsed_response['peers'] returns:
# [{"ip"=>"8.19.35.234", "peer id"=>"-lt0C20-\x90\xE0\xE6\x0E\xD0\x8A\xE5\xA2\xF2b(!",          
# "port"=>9898}]
peer_id = parsed_response['peers'].first['peer id']

send_string = "\023BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" << info_hash << peer_id

# ip and port are my current internet ip and 6881 respectively
client = TCPSocket.new ip, port

# What I'm sending over
client.send("\023BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" << info_hash << peer_id, 0)
len = client.recv(1)
puts len
```

Here's what `send_string` looks like in the end:
[image]

Comment: The info_hash in the send_string is a 40 byte hexencoded string, it should be a 20 byte raw binary string.

Answer (score 1):

While having handshake from your side,
PeerID used should be yours , not of the other side.

So your message should look like this :

```
peer_id = "-MY0001-123456654321"
client.send("\023BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" << info_hash << peer_id, 0)
```

If you are developing your own bit-torrent client then you can have your own format for peer id following standards mentioned by bit-torrent protocol.
You can read more about peer id here:
https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#peer_id

If you have any confusion in future , start any bittorrent client and follow [wire-shark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChapterIntroduction.html) packets. You will understand, where you are making mistake.

I am attaching a sample handshake message here :
[image]

Here "-KS0001-123456654321" is peerid for my bittorrent client.

Answer (score 0):

I cant write ruby. 
This is python code:

```
send_string = chr(19)+"BitTorrent Protocol"+8*chr(0)+info_hash+peer_id
```